# How to call generic method by reflection using InvokeMember

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reflection

I need to call a method via reflection. But the thing is that I don't want to find a method, I want to evaluate it at run-time using arguments. This is what I try to do:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var type = typeof(Test<int>);
        type.InvokeMember("Write", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null, new Test<int>(), new object[] {1, "1"});
        // The next call fails
        type.InvokeMember("Write", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null, new Test<int>(), new object[] { 2, 2 });
    }
}

public class Test<T>
{
    public void Write(T arg1, string arg2)
    {
        Console.Write(arg1);
        Console.Write(arg2);
        Console.WriteLine(" write1");
    }

    public void Write<T2>(T arg1, T2 arg2)
    {
        Console.Write(arg1);
        Console.Write(arg2);
        Console.WriteLine(" write2");
    }
}
```

The first call works fine but the second one generates an exception saying that Write() was not found. Can I call it using InvokeMember anyhow? I don't want trying to look for all methods and then call something like MakeGenericMethod()

Answer (score 0):

Your second invoke try to call `Write` method with two int input but doesn't find any method with this signature in  `Test` class.

You can move `T2` to class definition like this : `public class Test<T, T2>`
and set `T2` in type declaration like this : `var type = typeof(Test<int,int>)`

Final Code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var type = typeof(Test<int, long>);
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            type.InvokeMember("Write", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                null, instance, new object[] { 1, "1" });

            type.InvokeMember("Write", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                null, instance, new object[] { 2, 22 });
        }
    }

    public class Test<T, T2>
    {
        public void Write(T arg1, string arg2)
        {
            Console.Write(arg1);
            Console.Write(arg2);
            Console.WriteLine(" write1");
        }

        public void Write(T arg1, T2 arg2)
        {
            Console.Write(arg1);
            Console.Write(arg2);
            Console.WriteLine(" write2");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't control Test class = )
That's why the question says "generic"

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be it is not possible. Remarks section in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.invokemember?view=net-5.0) explicitly says that

> You cannot use `InvokeMember` to invoke a generic method.

Comment: So now what, how can we fix this problem?